# Is a PropertyChanged event handler bad if it is used for updating the database?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a class with several fields.

```
public          bool         Active       { get; set; }
public          List<Group>  Groups       { get; set; }
public          string       FirstName    { get; set; }
public          string       LastName     { get; set; }
public          Gender       Gender       { get; set; }
public          string       IdCard       { get; set; }
public          List<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
public          string       Address      { get; set; }
public          string       PicturePath  { get; set; }
public          string       Comments     { get; set; }
```

In the database, I have a table with corresponding fields. I want that whenever I change the value of this fields, the corresponding field in the table will be updated too automatically to the new value.

I thought maybe to implement a `PropertyChanged` event, and for that, I need to invoke the event handler from the `set`. The problem is that I read that [Property getters are expected to be fast and idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495864/logic-in-get-part-of-property-good-practice/495888#495888):

> Though it's perfectly fine to iterate over an in-memory collection of objects, I wouldn't recommend doing any kind of heavy lifting in either get or set parts. *Anton Gogolev*

But isn't database updating a "heavy lifting"? Is my solution bad? What other solution would you suggest?

Comment: "Property **getters** are expected to be fast": property **setters** are not mentioned. Your update happens when calling a property setter, right?

Comment: @MainMa - indeed, but then he said that he wouldn't recommend doing any kind of heavy lifting in either get or set parts. Your comment his helpful, please put it in an answer!

Comment: If you really feel a need to do this, have a second class listening for the property changed event and have it do the db work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best approach to update a database field when a corresponding class property changes?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/318701/what-is-the-best-approach-to-update-a-database-field-when-a-corresponding-class)

Comment: @Ger - not a duplicate. There I asked what approach to use. Here I have a question about the specific approach I chose.

Comment: @Sipo I feel like, `Is my solution bad? What other solution would you suggest?` is asking the same thing as, `What is the best approach...`

Comment: You should try to wrap groups of changes into a *transaction* (which can fail btw), instead of handling each change individually under the covers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few reasons against such approach.

- Leaky abstractions. Updating a database is not a risk-free thing. Bad things happen: network connection can be dropped while you're sending the update query; DNS server can be down; the database server can get out of space. When one calls a method such as `DAL.ProductRepository.Update(Product)`, the caller expects the risk of calling the method, and is expected, in turn, to catch exceptions or handle exceptional cases in any other way. On the other hand, when executing `currentProduct.Price = 123;`, it seems natural *not* to expect an SQL exception to be thrown, nor the main thread to be blocked for 30 seconds before the connection times out. By doing heavy database stuff in a setter, you make it easy for the caller to forget about the risks, which is not a good idea.
- Properties—would it be getters or setters—are expected to be fast, and by fast, I mean “the stuff which happens behind a getter or a setter remains relatively basic, both in terms of code and in terms of computing.” The reason for that is that callers *expect* them to be fast and don't expect too much work under the hood (here again, a 30-seconds wait time before the connection times out is a good example).
- This approach is simply uncommon, and so violates the [Principle of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). The common approach is to use whatever getter and setter, and only when all the needed changes are made to the object, pass this object to some *repository*, some object which owns the database context.
- In continuity with the previous point, if the object can update the database itself, it means that the object has database context or knows the connection string and is able to create the context from that. The approach *could* be problematic, and it is not clear in which layer would you put such class.

However:

- You may have a *very specific* need when updating database through `PropertyChanged` actually makes sense. I could imagine, for instance, an application configuration object which synchronizes itself with the database. Its nature is different from `Product`-style objects, which makes Principle of Least Surprise irrelevant. If class documentation is great and the culture of your team ensures that documentation *will* be read, the abstraction remains leaky, but the callers will be aware of the leaks before they actually happen. Again, such cases would be rare (and I haven't seen any yet), but remain valid.